# Laptop display dims when running on battery power

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, brightness

I recently bought a [Lenovo IdeaPad Y580](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/laptop/ideapad/y-series/y580/) and it has one minor annoyance: It continues to dim the screen when I unplug it from the power cord. I have tried setting the screen brightness in the advanced power settings but no matter what I set this to, the laptop always gets dimmer when unplugged.

[image]

So how can I keep the display brightness **at 15% at all times?**

Comment: Is the machine part of a corporate domain?  It may be set at a group policy level...

Comment: @francisswest No it's a personal computer.

Comment: @LucasMcCoy Is the issue solved ?

Comment: @Lamb no it's still dimming. I looked for the Lenovo Energy Management like you said, but it wasn't installed. I believe you're on the right track though. I'm going to see if it could be caused by a Lenovo driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, all the power settings in windows may be complete voids due to LENOVO's own power management application, 
Look for "**Lenovo Energy Management**" it should have some customisable settings.

If there are no such settings then Try disabling "**Lenovo Energy Management**", from **Task Manager**

If nothing works and if you are so desperate to achieve custom settings, Uninstall the Energy Management Software. (*Not Recommended*)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the "Dim display after" setting (it's just above those percentage settings) to 0, it should disable display dimming.

However, Lamb is right that Lenovo's Power Manager might be resetting whatever you set in the Windows control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Display screen goes dim after unplugging the powercord...for the Lenovo ideapad s10 hit the FN button and the Arrow Up key under the Enter and Shift keys. The arrow up key will increase the display light and the arrow down key will dim it. Hope this works.

Comment: This would be manually adjusting each time, there should be a setting not to dim on battery as well, but this could be useful if you want the default to dim and then manually change on one-off situations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an X61s, and it turned out it is a BIOS setting. In Config-Display set display brightness on battery to "high" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo Ideapad3205, and I simply went to "Edit Power Options" and increased the "on battery" setting to maximum - the same as the level already set for "on power".  It works perfectly and my screen no longer dims when not plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

In Win 11 open "Settings", "Display", "Brightness" on the right, hit the down arrow next to the brightness slider. Uncheck "Help improve battery life by optimizing the content shown and battery" and watch the brightness go back to full right away.That's it!

Comment: Welcome to SU. Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777037/edit) your answer and explain how exactly this helps OP to _"keep the display brightness at 15% at all times?"_